# Clever horizontal positioning in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Are there any built in css classes in jQuery Mobile for horizontal positioning? In Bootstrap, the screen is divided by 12 columns, and elements can be aligned based on them. Example: "col-md-2". http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

I want it to be fairly responsive in design. At the moment I'm thinking of using divs and set the "css width" to a percentage..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at jquerymobile responsive grids: [link](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/content/content-grids-responsive.html)

#### code:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b ui-responsive">
    <div class="ui-block-a">Column A</div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">Column B</div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">Column C</div>
</div>
```